# how to mock a method of a class

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

This is my controller code and I need to mock GetTokenDetails() method to conduct XUnit test on DecodeToken function. Am I doing in right way or not?

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [Route("DecodeToken")]
    public IActionResult DecodeToken()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var tokenResult = GetTokenDetails();

            var result = _employeeService.ServiceDecodeToken(tokenResult.UserName, tokenResult.Role);

            if (result.Httpcode == 200)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(500, result);
            }
        }
        else
            return BadRequest();
    }

    public GetTokenDetailsDto GetTokenDetails()
    {
        var token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
        var tokenbearer = token.Split(' ');
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var decodedtoken = handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenbearer[1]);
        string user = decodedtoken.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name").FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        string role = decodedtoken.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role").FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        var usr = user.Split(":");
        var rol = role.Split(":");
        string userName = usr[2].Trim();
        string userRole = rol[2].Trim();
        GetTokenDetailsDto getTokenDetailsDto = new GetTokenDetailsDto()
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Role = userRole,
        };
        return getTokenDetailsDto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Generally, I don't think there is a right way to do something.

There are multiple right ways to do it :). You just need to pick one or create one.

Second, I suggest you to create a new Dotnet standard Project under the same Solution and separate the logic from controllers. This way, you can create a Unit test project and import only the logic project.

Third, I see some points in your code that you are reading some value from the context( which is not avaiable in testing environment). For example, `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]`. these kind of data should be in the input arguments of the function `GetTokenDetails`, so you can provide some sample data to test in your UnitTestProject. Something like this:

```
public GetTokenDetailsDto GetTokenDetails(string token)
    {
        var tokenbearer = token.Split(' ');
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var decodedtoken = handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenbearer[1]);
        string user = decodedtoken.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name").FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        string role = decodedtoken.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role").FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        var usr = user.Split(":");
        var rol = role.Split(":");
        string userName = usr[2].Trim();
        string userRole = rol[2].Trim();
        GetTokenDetailsDto getTokenDetailsDto = new GetTokenDetailsDto()
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Role = userRole,
        };
        return getTokenDetailsDto;
    }
```